# jsonp getting 404 when calling Redmine API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp, redmine-api

I am trying to consume Redmine API from an angularjs project.

I ended up using jsonp in order to solve CORS problem.

I receive 404 when calling this:

```
var url = 'http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/issues.json?callback=displayIssues';
 $http({
                method: 'JSONP',
                url: url
            }).
            success(function (data, status) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("Error: " + status);
            });
...
    function displayIssues(issues) {
                console.log('displayIssues');
                ...
            }
```

But when I call the same url with Postman, it works.

Why do I receive this 404?

here is my console:

```
GET http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/issues.json?callback=displayIssues jsonpReq @ angular.js:8576(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8420sendReq @ angular.js:8291serverRequest @ angular.js:8025wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11498wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11498(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11584Scope.$eval @ angular.js:12608Scope.$digest @ angular.js:12420Scope.$apply @ angular.js:12712(anonymous function) @ angular.js:18980x.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
authentication.service.js:100 Error: 404
```

Rest API and jsonp are both enabled in the admin->setting->auth

I also tried:

```
        var url = 'http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/redmine/issues.json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        $http.jsonp(url, {
            params: {
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                format: 'json'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log('ok');
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

getting this:

```
GET http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/issues.json&callback=angular.callbacks._0?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&format=json jsonpReq @ angular.js:8576(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8420sendReq @ angular.js:8291serverRequest @ angular.js:8025wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11498wrappedCallback @ angular.js:11498(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11584Scope.$eval @ angular.js:12608Scope.$digest @ angular.js:12420Scope.$apply @ angular.js:12712(anonymous function) @ angular.js:18980x.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5y.handle @ jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5
services.js:35 error: undefined
```

Also, when calling this:

```
var url = 'http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/redmine/issues.json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
            $http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
                console.log('success');
            }).error(function (error) {
                console.log('error:: ' + error);
            });
```

I get the same error

Please consider that muser, mpasswd and myredmine are just examples.

Comment: Have you tested the url via Postman? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have tested it, but the url I wrote (myredmine) is just an example

Comment: What is the result when you send a GET to this url via postman?

Comment: it's all the issues that my account have. displayIssues({"issues":[{"id":1831,"project":{"id":167,...

Comment: You have error 404, make sure to get rid of that first in postman...

Comment: it works in postman, I will edit my question to make it clearer

Comment: isn't that `params: { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'...`  
 redundant since you already defined that in the url?

Comment: you have another typo `.../issues.json&callback=..` should be `../issues.json?callback=..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ngDocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp):

> The name of the callback should be the string JSON_CALLBACK

Angular will replace that string internally with an `angular.callbacks_{0-9a-z}`

So first change your code to this:

```
var url = 'http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/redmine/issues.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$http.jsonp(url).succe...
```

Playing with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koox00/zeh2haby/) it seems that [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/trunk/lib/redmine/views/builders/json.rb#L30) strips the dot `.` from urls thus making `angular.callbacks_0` to `angularcallback_0` which is undefined.
You can read more on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1551), there is an issue about this.

#### POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS

**1)** There is a hack posted by another user on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329581/4159720) to change the name of the callback to a custom one.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koox00/p32ydtjo/) according to @Todi-Adiatmo's hack.

**2)** Another solution according to @dancras found on the issue posted on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1551#issuecomment-15675006) is to define the undefined `angularcallbacks_{..}` with the call to `angular.callbacks_{..}` and then delete the global `angularcallbacks_`.
You have to use this immediately before the jsonp call:

```
var c = $window.angular.callbacks.counter.toString(36);

$window['angularcallbacks_' + c] = function (data) {
    $window.angular.callbacks['_' + c](data);
    delete $window['angularcallbacks_' + c];
};
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koox00/zeh2haby/9/) according to @danca's solution.

Comment: I dont understand, shall I use a workaround in order to make it work with Redmine API? If so, what happens when they fix it?

Comment: according to the issue page on github angular team isn't oing to change this. It's up to the redmine team I guess. You can always set up CORS correctly and use json instead of jsonp

Comment: I've updated my answer. added links to read more info about this. there is also an issue on redmine http://www.redmine.org/issues/13718#change-58154

Comment: how to setup CORS correctly with redmine and use json?

Comment: maybe it's better to make a new question about that so we don't bloat this one and also get more help :)

Comment: thank you for your time, but I cannot accept this answer, because it doesnt fix the jsonp issue, neither is very well explained because first it says that there is a problem in my code and then offer other solutions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99209/discussion-between-koox00-and-eeadev).

Answer (score 0):

I see your console showing this:-

GET http://muser:mpasswd@myredmine/issues.json?callback=displayIssues

That's not technically a valid URL in HTTP.  The username and password, shouldn't be in the GET call they should be in the header, according to.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

A quick search on google found this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and 
[angularjs basic authentication headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954024/angularjs-basic-authentication-headers)

I've not looked at redmine for years, and it might handle dodgy HTTP fine simply with the options earlier answers have specified, but if that doesn't work, check if the request is actually getting to Redmine properly