# AngularJs equivalent of this CURL

Tags: angularjs, spring, curl, spring-boot

We have a simple auth2 applciation (like [this](https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot)) that works, when called from CURL, but we have a problem getting the token from angular http

So the question is: what is the equivalent of this curl in angular:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" my-client-with-secret:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

We tried to set the `Authorization` header 
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Basic <'secret:secret' in Base64>";

but we got 401 unauthorized

Comment: Have you seen http://olefriis.blogspot.co.at/2014/01/http-basic-authentication-in-angularjs.html or http://www.jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get basic auth working in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959563/how-do-i-get-basic-auth-working-in-angularjs)