# AngularJS - http request with Basic Auth (connect to FreeNAS)

Tags: python, angularjs, api, httprequest

Im trying to connect to the REST API of FreeNAS (http://api.freenas.org/authentication.html) within my AngularJS app. The API uses basic authentication with username and password.

In python this is a very easy thing as there is only one line of code:

```
requests.get('http://freenas.mydomain/api/v1.0/account/bsdusers/',auth=('root', 'freenas'))
```

I tried to find something for AngularJS but stumbled only over excrutiating code, e.g. [How do I get basic auth working in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959563/how-do-i-get-basic-auth-working-in-angularjs)

Is there anything available like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://freenas.mydomain/api/v1.0/account/bsdusers/',
  auth: ['username':'root', 'password':'pw']
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function for encoding the user and password in Base64("username:password") and add Authorization header.

You can try encoding your username and password over here https://www.base64encode.org/ and see if it works. "root:freenas" being cm9vdDpmcmVlbmFz you can try the code below.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic cm9vdDpmcmVlbmFz';
```

Once you get it working get implement the Base64 factory you posted ( [How do I get basic auth working in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959563/how-do-i-get-basic-auth-working-in-angularjs) )

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; 
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('root' + ':' + 'freenas');
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://freenas.mydomain/api/v1.0/account/bsdusers/'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```